# What Bazel incantation do I need to include gRPC reflection header file?

Tags: bazel

When I try to compile a bazel project that uses gRPC reflection, I get the following error.

```
 fatal error: external/com_github_grpc_grpc/src/proto/grpc/reflection/v1alpha/reflection.grpc.pb.h: No such file or directory
```

In my WORKSPACE, I have the following bindings:

```
def _com_github_grpc_grpc():
    external_http_archive("com_github_grpc_grpc")
    external_http_archive("build_bazel_rules_apple")

    # Rebind some stuff to match what the gRPC Bazel is expecting.
    native.bind(
        name = "protobuf_headers",
        actual = "@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_headers",
    )
    native.bind(
        name = "libssl",
        actual = "//external:ssl",
    )
    native.bind(
        name = "cares",
        actual = "//external:ares",
    )

    native.bind(
        name = "grpc",
        actual = "@com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc++",
    )
```

In my BUILD file, I have the following `deps`:

```
    deps = [
        "//external:protobuf_headers",
        "//external:grpc",
    ],
```

What additional incantations do I need for the include at the top of the question?

Comment: I think you need to add a dependency on grpc++_reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a spelunking through issues, I figured out that I need the following WORKSPACE

```
workspace(name = "xxx")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "com_github_grpc_grpc",
    strip_prefix = "grpc-master",
    urls = ["https://github.com/grpc/grpc/archive/master.tar.gz"],
)

load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_deps.bzl", "grpc_deps")
grpc_deps()

load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_extra_deps.bzl", "grpc_extra_deps")
grpc_extra_deps()
```

and the following BUILD:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "ReflectionPlay",
    copts = ["-std=c++17"],
    srcs = ["reflection_play.cc"],
    deps = [
        "@com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc++",
        "@com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc++_reflection",
        "@com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpcpp_admin",
    ],
)
```

Comment: I _think_ you don't need the `:grpcpp_admin` dependency; that's used to enable the [admin interface](https://github.com/lidizheng/proposal/blob/admin-interface/A38-admin-interface-api.md) which is not (directly) related to service reflection, and [requires changes to the server startup code](https://github.com/lidizheng/proposal/blob/admin-interface/A38-admin-interface-api.md#start-admin-server-without-code-change) to enable.